# Add AAD user account via group to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-server-2019

I've an Azure Devops Organization and Azure Active Directory.
In my Azure Active Directory, there's a group called ***#Developers#***. The members of the ***#Developers#*** also need access to Azure DevOps.

Right now, i'm adding each user individually to the AD Group ***#Developers#*** and then again to the AzureDevOps Organization.

How it possible, that all members of the AAD group  ***#Developers#*** are automatically added to AzureDevOps, can i add the group there?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the Users Area it is not possible becuase you handle Access Level (read: License) per User, not per Group. You can only add AD or AAD Groups on Permissions Area, where you can manage Group Access (e.g. Developers in AAD can be added to Contributers ADO Group). Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-ad-aad-built-in-security-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

For Admin Access i would recomend JIT and a dedicated AAD ADO Admin Group.